# Html2pdf hindi support

Tags: pdf, yii, html2pdf

I am using html2pdf in my Yii application to generate Pdf's, This is my code

Some 'Hindi' or 'Tamil' words are need to show in the pdf.

How can I get this?

sample code and generated Pdf are below, it shows either '?' or squares

```
    $html2pdf = Yii::app()->ePdf->HTML2PDF();
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('L', 'A4', 'en');
    $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('freesans');
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('attentancepdf', array(), true));
    $html2pdf->Output($batch_name);
```

[image: **output**]

Answer (score 0):

```
<span align="center"><h4><?php echo Yii::t('app','CLASS STUDENT ATTENDANCE'); ?></h4></span>
```

I have removed the "h4" tag then its worked , I dont know how!?

Also 'b' tag !!

```
<td width="150"><b><?php echo Yii::t('app','Batch'); ?></b></td>
```

[image: result]